# Tensorflow data parallelism

Tags: parallel-processing, tensorflow

I am trying to implement data parallelism with tensorflow using the [eexample replicated training documentation here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/)

In the example code of the link above, the ps jobs seems to do nothing but blocking on the join operation:

```
if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
server.join()
```

All the data parallelism of the computation can be taken care of by the supervisor. So what is the role of the parameter server? and can it be stopped gracefully after the jobs are done?